# How do I Create multiple starting points for my AR Navigation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I would like to have multiple starting points. I wish to add buttons or dropdown that would list different starting point such that when selected the AR Session will recenter to the selected location.

I tried using QR codes to recenter, it works when I Spacebar to debug but in real world testing its not scanning[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HThl7.png)